# Finding all instances of a pattern in a string in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a command parser for an account storage tool in python and have the basics down fine.

the user enters a command into the programs interpreter (not command line args) like `[+] -u peter -e myemail@email.com -p password`

my problem comes as a use case from the command above, I've been splinting the strings on '-' to get a list like so `['u peter', 'e myemail@email.com', 'p password']` but what if the user has a '-' in their username, email or password like this `-p pass-word` I would end up with `['u peter', 'e myemail@email.com', 'p pass', 'word']`

I've been investigating regex to split the commands but cant quite nail it down. I've got this so far `\-[a-z][^\-]*` but it splits up the 'pass-word' style parameter too.

does anyone know of the correct or intelligent way to do this, because at this stage I'm clutching at straws.

Thanks,
Peter

*** EDIT ***

So for the solution that closest fits my needs I followed @samkhan13's answer and abandoned regex thanks to the advice many of you gave. Here is my solution that works with my usecase as long as the user does have a command surrounded by whitespace in their password and if they do they can just go use better software!

```
def parseString(userInput):
    poslist = [userInput.find(' -u '),
               userInput.find(' -e '),
               userInput.find(' -p '),
               userInput.find(' -s '),
               userInput.find(' -g ')]
    poslist.sort()
    poslist = filter(lambda a: a != -1, poslist)
    text = []
    for j in range(poslist.__len__()-1):
        text.append(userInput[poslist[j]+2:poslist[j+1]])

    text.append(userInput[poslist[poslist.__len__()-1]+2:])
    return text
```

input >> `'   -e myemail@email.com     -p    pa"-ussword'`

output >> `['e myemail@email.com    ', 'p    pa"-ussword']`

*** EDIT ***

and heres a regex one that deals with unknown commands

```
def parseString(userInput):
    poslist = []
    text = []
    p = re.compile("\s-[a-z]\s") #searches for unix style commands
    for m in p.finditer(userInput):
        poslist.append(m.start())

    for j in range(poslist.__len__()-1):
        text.append(userInput[poslist[j]+2:poslist[j+1]])

    text.append(userInput[poslist[poslist.__len__()-1]+2:])
    return text
```

input >> `'   -e myemail@email.com -p pa"-ussword -x pmck'`

output >> `['e myemail@email.com', 'p pa"-ussword', 'x pmck']`

Comment: Take a look at `argparse` module. Maybe you find something useful there: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html

Comment: Are each of the parameters (e.g. `peter`, `myemail@email.com`, `password`) guaranteed to contain no spaces?

Comment: How do you handle commands with spaces in the arguments?

Comment: @senshin no there is no guarantee. So far I have been able to cope with whitespace but not have the `-` character in one of the params

Comment: Is you command line language fixed? Can you change it? As a recommendation: define a simple grammar (actions, objects, modifiers) and use either a regex or a parser to parse the grammar you have defined. Take a look at [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com)

Comment: @user3215684 Then what if someone's password is "pass -u peter"? They would have to enter `-p pass -u peter`, which makes this indistinguishable from somebody whose password is `pass` and whose username is `peter`. This will be a difficult problem if you can't change the way you accept information from your users.

Comment: @senshin I see your point any suggestions on a better way to deal with the input? is there a way to sanitize args or would a custom command format like `<p>pass-word` be better?

Comment: If the parameter can't be of the form `-p "pass -u word"`, then something like `((.*?)(?= -))|(.+$)` could work. Else this needs a little bit more work :/

Comment: Why all this position nonsense. You wrote the first half of the regex `\s-[a-z]\s` why not just add to it to get the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your use case is that specific you can avoid regex all together.

```
def parseString(userInput):
    namePosition = userInput.find('-u')
    emailPosition = userInput.find('-e')
    passwordPosition = userInput.find('-p')

    if namePosition != -1 and emailPosition != -1 and passwordPosition != -1:
        nameText = userInput[namePosition+1:emailPosition] # will look like 'u peter'
        emailText = userInput[emailPosition+1:passwordPosition]
        passwordText = userInput[passwordPosition+1:]
        return [nameText,emailText,passwordText]
    else:
        print 'improper number or type of parameters given as input'

someText = '-u peter -e myemail@email.com -p password'

parsedText = parseString(someText)
print parsedText
```

try modifying the above example if you suspect that the user should be allowed to input a variety of text using either of `-u`, `-e`, `-p` or some other `-x`

Comment: I like this but it doesn't match some use cases as some fields are not required and the order must be unimportant. I'll have a look at modifying the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about this pattern for password: `((^|\s)-p\s)[^\s$]+` ? it works fine for `pass-word`

Answer (score 0):

This pattern

```
-[^ ].*?(?:'.*?'|".*?")?(?:(?= -\S)|$)
```

matches the parameters, even if there is a `-` in the password, even if the parameter is following this pattern: `-p "bar -u foo"`.

Does it solve your issue?

**Warning**

As @shenshin pointed out, `-p "a "" - b"` isn't matched. Many weird cases won't be caught here, the quick regex answer may be a "quickfix" for this but for more strong and secure solutions you'll probably have to turn to another tool.

Comment: Calling `re.findall(<pattern>, '-p "a "" - b"')` yields `['-p "a ""', '- b"']`. Valiant attempt, but regexes just aren't going to solve OP's problem.

Comment: Indeed... However, `-p "a "" - b"` seems like a pretty unlikely/unwanted parameter. I guess it depends on the scope on which OP is planning to use this.

Comment: That is so far above my understanding of regex but yes so far it seems to work unless user has a `"` somewhere in the password. its all fine until a user hits a certain edge case and the whole thing crumbles

Comment: It still works if the parameter is `-p 'bar "foo'`, but it breaks on `-p pass"word`... There may be too many weird cases to safely list them by hand. If you want a strong and fully secure answer you probably will have to turn to something else than quickly typed regex :) This is indeed only useful if you want some kind of quick light parse.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably way more than you're asking for.

Its not that complicated.  Each section is the same.
The only difference is the command letter u,e,p.

The expression matches only the commands in it, so others can be mixed in but won't be matched.
The commands can be in any order, and even not there at all.
Each command is strictly  delimeted, so there  can be hyphens/spaces in thier values.
Only the value is captured, leading/trailing whitespace trimmed.

**edited**
To add more commands, just copy a segment to the bottom and change the command letter. All lower case letters a-z are assumed to be commands and have to be in the strict form to be considered a command. Otherwise its part of the value.

Thats it, I tested in Perl, works like a charm. If you want to see that test case, let me know.

```
 # ^(?=.*(?:^\s*|\s-)u\s+((?:[^\s-]+|(?!\s*-[a-z]\s|\s*$)[\s-]+)*))?(?=.*(?:^\s*|\s-)e\s+((?:[^\s-]+|(?!\s*-[a-z]\s|\s*$)[\s-]+)*))?(?=.*(?:^\s*|\s-)p\s+((?:[^\s-]+|(?!\s*-[a-z]\s|\s*$)[\s-]+)*))?


 ^ 
 (?=
      .* 
      (?: ^ \s* | \s - )
      u \s+ 
      (                             # (1)
           (?:
                [^\s-]+ 
             |  (?! \s* - [a-z] \s | \s* $ )
                [\s-]+ 
           )*
      )
 )?
 (?=
      .* 
      (?: ^ \s* | \s - )
      e \s+ 
      (                             # (2)
           (?:
                [^\s-]+ 
             |  (?! \s* - [a-z] \s | \s* $ )
                [\s-]+ 
           )*
      )
 )?
 (?=
      .* 
      (?: ^ \s* | \s - )
      p \s+ 
      (                             # (3)
           (?:
                [^\s-]+ 
             |  (?! \s* - [a-z] \s | \s* $ )
                [\s-]+ 
           )*
      )
 )?
```

**edit2**
This is a test case in Perl.
If needed, you can name the capture groups. In the sample they are numbered.
Example:

```
 (?=
      .* 
      (?: ^ \s* | \s - )
      p \s+ 
      (?P<password>
           (?:
                [^\s-]+ 
             |  (?! \s* - [a-z] \s | \s* $ )
                [\s-]+ 
           )*
      )
 )?
```

Test case

```
 $/ = undef;
 my $str = <DATA>;

 if ( $str =~ /^(?=.*(?:^\s*|\s-)u\s+((?:[^\s-]+|(?!\s*-[a-z]\s|\s*$)[\s-]+)*))?(?=.*(?:^\s*|\s-)e\s+((?:[^\s-]+|(?!\s*-[a-z]\s|\s*$)[\s-]+)*))?(?=.*(?:^\s*|\s-)p\s+((?:[^\s-]+|(?!\s*-[a-z]\s|\s*$)[\s-]+)*))?/s)
 {
     print "user = '$1'\n";
     print "email = '$2'\n";
     print "password = '$3'\n";

 }
 __DATA__

 This string has commands -x, -e, -y, -p, -u commands it it 

   -x XVA-LUE -e  asdf-myemail@-email.com -y YVA-LUE -p pa'-#@-p,s"sword -z ZVA-LUE -u  Pe-ter
```

Output >>

```
 user = 'Pe-ter'
 email = 'asdf-myemail@-email.com'
 password = 'pa'-#@-p,s"sword'
```

Comment: going to give this a mull over to try wrap my head around it, I'll get back to you to let you know how it works out. Cheers for the help, its appreciated.

Comment: @pmck - You must have regex phobia. A single regex will do everything for you. This one -> `\s-(?P<Cmd>[a-z])\s+(?P<Val>(?:[^\s-]+|(?!\s*-[a-z]\s|\s*$)[\s-]+)*)` finds all the commands and values, trims it up and its ready for consumption. No need to parse/re-parse/sort, etc.. Just sit in a search loop and read `Cmd` and `Val`.